# Is solving the PvsNP example question a solution to PvsNP?

Tags: number-theory, computer-science, np-complete

This example question was created by the claymath institute. The PvsNP question states, suppose the dean leaves you with a task to house a group of 400 students inside dorms. But there is only enough room for 100 students. And to make things worse , every student has a list of other students that they are incompatable with. And the number of combinations it would take to sort out a perfect 100 students is more than the number of atoms in our known universe. My question is, if I solve this example problem, and I show my solution could solve any variance of this problem, does that mean I solved PvsNP?

Comment: You have to solve it in polynomial time for arbitrarily many students, not just 400.

Comment: In other words, with $n$ students, how long does your algorithm take?

Comment: It should be pointed out that if you prove P=NP, taking the million from the Clay Institute would probably be the stupidest thing you could do.  The inventors of such an algorithm could enrich themselves beyond the dreams of greed or avarice with no help from the Clay Institute.  The prize money is to encourage work in the other direction.

Comment: I agree, but I dont have much programming knowledge to argue with a million dollars. I just have an unorthodox solution written in basic math terms, im not even sure if they would except it like that.btw, Do you think this example question is NP complete?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is an example of an NP-complete problem, meaning that if you found a polynomial time algorithm to solve it, then yes, you would have solved $P = NP$.

However, just finding an algorithm (not in polynomial time) does not say anything about P vs. NP.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: well, my algorithm is very quick and short, it can be very quick and short, but im not sure how to measure n. lets just put it this way, I personaly could sort out the 100 students out in about 3 minutes. So if a computer did it , it would be almost an instant being done in a couple steps. It does take a little polynomial time seeing as it has to follow such steps, but it does it takes a lot less than %1 of the time it would take checking every possible combination. BTW, why does everyone put their real name down instead of an alias?